# Reorder django core functionality

Tags: python, django, multilingual, sites

I faced the problem of the Django multi-site project. Each site can handle multiple languages. Project handle languages by URL and we don’t use default language prefix. For example

- Site one: root `/` specify Russian language and `/en` specify English version of the site (default language is Russian)
- Site two: root `/` specify English language and `/ru` specify Russian version of the site (default language is English)

Django has a problem. Framework cache resolver and store prefixes for some sites.

When I begin to use different default languages for different domains I was confused with the wrong prefixes. I must change the behaviour of the Django `get_resolver()` function because of hist `@functools.lru_cache decorator`

This is the Django file:

```
def get_resolver(urlconf=None):
    if urlconf is None:
        urlconf = settings.ROOT_URLCONF
    return _get_cached_resolver(urlconf)


@functools.lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def _get_cached_resolver(urlconf=None):
    return URLResolver(RegexPattern(r'^/'), urlconf)
```

Can I do something to disable the cache? Or make cache depend on the site?

I tried to reorder the function in the Django core module

My solution is:

```
from django.urls.resolvers import URLResolver, RegexPattern

@functools.lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def get_resolver_for_site(site_id, urlconf):
    return URLResolver(RegexPattern(r'^/'), urlconf)


def _get_cached_resolver_for_site(urlconf=None):
    return get_resolver_for_site(get_site().id, urlconf)


@receiver(post_save, sender=SiteSettings)
def clear_url_resolver_cache(sender, **kwargs):
    get_resolver_for_site.cache_clear()


resolvers._get_cached_resolver = _get_cached_resolver_for_site
```

So I defined a custom function, that return URL resolver and cache it depends on the site. I think this is not clear and it is a crutch.

Thank you.

**UPDATE**

> I was confused with the wrong prefixes

If I have different default languages for first site and second site - I have url prefix for default language for one of my sites in a project (Really I don't want language prefix for default language).

In other words Django caches prefix for default language for first site and it affects the second site.

Comment: Could you add more specific details to `I was confused with the wrong prefixes`? What was the expected result and what is the actual result?

Comment: Can you not just override `settings.ROOT_URLCONF` for each site?

Comment: I have the same url conf for all my sites in a project. One more problem is that urlconf argument is passing to get_resolver(urlconf=None) from django core functions. I am not sure django do not use this argument in the code anywhere :)